# Regex that match when beginning & end is of the same length

Tags: python, regex

How do you make a regex that match when the beginning and the end is of the same length?
For example

```
>>> String = '[[A], [[B]], [C], [[D]]]'
>>> Result = re.findall(pattern, String)
>>> Result
>>> [ '[A]', '[[B]]', '[C]', '[[D]]' ]
```

Currently I use the pattern `\[.*?\]` but it resulted in

```
>>> ['[[A]', '[[B]', '[C]', '[[D]']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to do.  Explain why your actual match is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define such a regular expression for a finite number of beginning/end characters (ie, something like "if it starts and ends with 1, or starts and ends with 2, or etc").  You, however, *cannot* do this for an unlimited number of characters.  This is simply a fact of regular expressions.  Regular expressions are the language of finite-state machines, and finite-state machines cannot do counting; at least the power of a pushdown-automaton (context-free grammar) is needed for that.

Put simply, a regular expression can say: "I saw *x* and then I saw *y*" but it *cannot* say "I saw *x* and then I saw *y* the same number of times" because it cannot remember how many times it saw *x*.

However, you can easily do this using the full power of the Python programming language, which is Turing-complete!  Turing-complete languages can definitely do counting:

```
>>> string = '[[A], [[B]], [C], [[D]]]'
>>> sameBrackets = lambda s: len(re.findall('\[',s)) == len(re.findall('\]',s))
>>> filter(sameBrackets, string.split(", "))
['[[B]]', '[C]']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Sorry.

Python's regular expressions are an extension of "finite state automata", which only allow a finite amount of memory to be kept as you scan through the string for a match. This example requires an arbitrary amount of memory, depending on how many repetitions there are.

The only way in which Python allows more than just finite state is with "backreferences", which let you match an identical copy of a previously matched portion of the string -- but they don't allow you to match something with, say, the same number of characters.

You should try writing this by hand, instead.

Answer (score 0):

To match balanced brackets you need a [recursive regular expression](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/recursive-regular-expressions/). The stock `re` module doesn't support this syntax, but the alternative [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) does:

```
import regex

r = r'\[(([^\[\]]+)|(?R))*\]'

print regex.match(r, '[[A], [[B]], [C], [[D]] ]') # ok
print regex.match(r, '[[A], [[B]], [C , [[D]] ]') # None
```

That expression basically says: match something surrounded by brackets, where "something" is either  a series of non-brackets `([^\[\]]+)` or the whole thing once again `(?R)`.